# Notification sound android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, ringtonemanager

I am currently developing an app and its notification system is working well. Except when i send a message from firebase to the phone the notification does not make a sound (default phone sound). The question is what is going wrong in my java program.

```
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, page1.class);//**The activity that you want to open when the notification is clicked
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Repalce following line in your code:

```
 Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.cutomSound);
```

This way You can access your custom notification sound.